# Как можно минимизировать и адаптировать SQL запрос с помощью JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Добрый день. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно минимизировать и адаптировать SQL запрос с помощью `JOIN`.
Сам запрос, который выполняеться `->fetchAll()`.

```
SELECT * FROM reviews,users 
WHERE reviews.rev_user_id_to = :user_id AND
      reviews.rev_user_id_from = users.user_id AND
      reviews.rev_status = "approved"
UNION ALL SELECT * FROM reviews,users
WHERE reviews.rev_user_id_from IS NULL AND
      reviews.rev_user_id_to = users.user_id AND
      users.user_id = :user_id AND
      reviews.rev_status = "approved"
```

Comment: `:user_id` — это что за синтаксис такой? place holder какой-то?

Comment: Это PDOStatement::bindValue(); Фактически это выглядит вот так $this->db->bind(':user_id', $user_id); - входящие данные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала можно избавиться от UNION'а:

```
SELECT * FROM reviews, users 
WHERE reviews.rev_user_id_to = :user_id AND
      reviews.rev_status = "approved" AND
      ( reviews.rev_user_id_from = users.user_id OR
        ( reviews.rev_user_id_to = users.user_id AND
          reviews.rev_user_id_from IS NULL
        )
      )
```

Затем, можно перенести все соответствующие условия в JOIN фразу:

```
SELECT * FROM reviews
INNER JOIN users ON ( 
  reviews.rev_user_id_from = users.user_id OR
    ( reviews.rev_user_id_to = users.user_id AND
      reviews.rev_user_id_from IS NULL
    )
  )
WHERE reviews.rev_user_id_to = :user_id AND
      reviews.rev_status = "approved"
```

Но, во-первых, надо проверить, что это сработает, а, во-вторых, на все три варианта запроса стоит посмотреть [`EXPLAIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html): возможно оптимизатор достаточно умный чтобы проделать это всё самостоятельно, а также может быть, что вместо таких ручных оптимизации нужно просто создать правильные индексы...